Execute UI Automation using Selenium Java in head mode through Jenkins in Linux agent(slave) machine
Both of controller(master) and agent(slave) machine are Linux systems and physical devices.
The connection is established successfully through agent.jar file. But the chromedriver is not getting initialized no matter what so, there's no browser opening in the agent machine.
Tried to install Xvfb plugin in Jenkins but still the chrome browser is not opening.
Also, here's the chromeprefs and chrome options used in the selenium test repo -
private static ChromeOptions getChromeOptions() {
        ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
        chromeOptions.setExperimentalOption("excludeSwitches", Collections.singletonList("enable-logging"));
        chromeOptions.setExperimentalOption("excludeSwitches", Collections.singletonList("enable-automation"));
        chromeOptions.setExperimentalOption("prefs", getChromePrefs());
        chromeOptions.setUnhandledPromptBehaviour(UnexpectedAlertBehaviour.IGNORE);
        chromeOptions.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_INSECURE_CERTS, false);
        chromeOptions.addArguments("start-maximized");
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
        chromeOptions.addArguments("start-maximized");
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--deny-permission-prompts");
        return chromeOptions;
    }
    
    private static Map<String, Object> getChromePrefs() {
        Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<>();
        prefs.put("download.default_directory", Paths.downloadsDirectory);
        prefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
        prefs.put("profile.content_settings.exceptions.automatic_downloads.*.setting", 1);
        prefs.put("profile.default_content_setting_values.geolocation", 0);
        prefs.put("credentials_enable_service", false);
        prefs.put("profile.password_manager_enabled", false);
        return prefs;
    }

Expectation -
On running the selenium job on controller, the chrome browser should open in the Jenkins and run smoothly.
